# Log 4 net not logging for the same url

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, log4net

I have created an error handler for my WCF Service using the log4net dll.After adding to the tfs my logging is not working, I have also set the configuration but the logging is not happening although in my test application it is working fine. kindly help.

Comment: can you please put in the configurations that you used in your sample app and in your main wcf serice ??

Answer (score 0):

You could [enable debugging in log4net](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx) by adding the following to your configuration file in the `appSettings` section:

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

As stated in the article, point the trace to some file like:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add 
        name="textWriterTraceListener" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
        initializeData="C:\my-log4net-trace.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

See the [full description over in the log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug).